# Covering the 100% of a div width with a span

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem with style. I have the following html structure and I can't change it, I'm only allowed to change the styling (css code) not the structure of the document. I need the input to cover the 100% of the width of the red div, but as it's contained within a span, I can not fit it well.

```
<div style="width: 100%;">
    <div style="background-color: red; width: 100%;">
        <span>&nbsp;</span>
        <label>App name</label>
        <span class="value">
            <input style = "width:100%"/>
        </span>
        <span class="required-icon">*</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, can you help me with styling? Here [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vp986ajj/2/).
Thanks a LOT!

Comment: the span is 100% the width of your div. Only the input is bigger because of its border. Try border:none for input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stealing the input's border or padding is cheating, and might not be what you want to achieve.

Instead, add `box-sizing: border-box;` to `input`:

(updated fiddle):

```
input{
    background:yellow;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

By default, the `width: 100%` refers to the input's content, i.e. without its padding. To refer the width to the actual border (which most of us would probably expect), use the css property mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `padding:0` and either can do `border:0` or either `width: calc(100% - 3px);`.

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vp986ajj/5/).